How to get model field types in pydantic v2?
I am trying to write a generic class that takes a pydantic model type, however the model can only have string fields. So i am trying to verify this at runtime.
I looked and found this answer, but it does not seem to work in v2 as the FieldInfo type that is returned as the values of the dict from model_info does not have a type_ property.

Solution is to use field.annotation (see):
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    c: list[float]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for field_name, field in MyModel.model_fields.items():
        print(field_name, field.annotation, type(field.annotation))

gives:
a <class 'int'> <class 'type'>
b <class 'str'> <class 'type'>
c list[float] <class 'types.GenericAlias'>

